# Target hyphenated attributes with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I target this link's custom attribute using CSS being that it is hyphenated?

```
<a href="#" liquid-goodness="milk">Milk Jug</a>
```

I've tried:

```
a[liquid-goodness="milk"]{ color:red; }
a["liquid-goodness"="milk"]{ color:red; }
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: The former approach (`a[liquid-goodness="milk"]{ color:red; }`) should work, did you try it? What went wrong?

Comment: First one works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/02xkf2oo/

Comment: I couldn't find this when searching. So this will give someone a resource in the future.

Comment: I refreshed too soon, before my stylesheet ran through my pre-processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example is the correct example:

```
a[liquid-goodness="milk"]{ color:red; }
```

Thanks to David Thomas

Additional resource with examples:

http://css-tricks.com/multiple-attribute-values
(Thanks, [Josh Palmeri](http://joshpalmeri.com))

Answer (score -1):

Include an id in your HTML

```
<a href="#" liquid-goodness="milk" id="lg">Milk Jug</a>
```

then in your CSS, try

```
 #lg {color: red;}
```